# Bootstrap navigation bar does not fill the top of the widow,

Tags: jquery, css

I have problem with my navigation bar. My links should fill the whole of top even when I resize my window. I have used a jquery to solve the problem men it does not work. Many thanks for any help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  (function( $ ){
    $.fn.autowidth = function() {
      return this.each(function() {        
       $('li', this).css({'width' : (100 / $('li', this).length) + '%'})
      });
     };
   })( jQuery );

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav > ul').autowidth();    
   });
  </script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">

   <ul class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   </ul>

   <ul class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <li><a href="#">The Company</a></li>
   </ul>

   <ul class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
   </ul>

   <ul class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
   </ul>

  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: would you create a jsfiddle that includes the bootstrap css at lease?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to keep four links in one line when resizing the window?

You just need to change the ul class from "col-xs-6" to "col-xs-3".

You can get more information about this css class here [grid-options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution for your problem
HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<ul class="col-xs-2 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<li><a href="#">The Company</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Use latest bootstrap and latest jquery

[Demo as fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpwm57g4/ "Fiddle example)

Comment: when you expand to 1024 menu will be auto adjusted